# Terminology vs jargon vs lexicon

Tags: differences

Though this subject is somewhat discussed at [Difference between “jargon” and “technical terms”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/113689/80007), what are the differences?

From Merriam-Webster online:

**[Jargon:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jargon)** *The technical terminology or characteristic idiom of a special activity or group.*

**[Terminology:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terminology)** *The special words or phrases that are used in a particular field.*

**[Lexicon:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lexicon)** *The words used in a language or by a person or group of people.* (Also: *The vocabulary of a language, an individual speaker or group of speakers, or a subject.*)

Can you please give examples where it is appropriate to use only one but not others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **lexicon** is just a catalog or dictionary of terms.  **Terminology** is the set of specialized terms in my field of study.  These items are clearly understood by others in my field of study.

**Jargon** is a set of terms used by people in other fields of study.  These terms are confusing, ambiguous and frustrating.

Comment: I disagree that a jargon must be ambiguous.  It is just that the precise meaning in that field does not match the dictionary definition outside the field. When a particle physicist uses "strangeness" or "charm" it has a precise meaning to them and others in the field.

Comment: Me too. And I disagree that jargon is something that only others use.  In my groups we have our own jargons.  Similarly, a physicist's terminology is no less such, just because I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 5):

Although not stated in the dictionary quotations above, I would say that jargon has a derogatory association, whilst terminology is neutral.  hence:

My partner might say to me "stop speaking jargon", not "stop speaking terminology".
Whilst I might ask an expert on a subject "what is the correct terminology for..." and not "what is the correct jargon for..."

Comment: Jargon can be local or informal additions to technical terminology; terms used in a certain field in one location, but not necessarily used in the same field in another location. Technical terminology for mechanics can be generally understood from place to place; but local jargon from a shop in New York might not be understood in Seattle.

Answer (score 3):

Jargon may be used for the special language developed by sailors, soldiers, pilots, students or any other special group. It 's a language that normal speakers don't understand. Mostly the term is negative, a neutral term would be "special group language.